# Separate Twilio caller ID

Tags: sip, twilio, telephony

I have many e-shops, every shop has it's own ladline twilio phone number.

All phone numbers redirect calls to my single mobile phone.

The problem is - I don't know from which shop the call is.

Is there any solution to tag somehow redirected calls?

I need to know that client is calling to shop1, so I would not ask him which shop is he calling.

If my mobile phone could handle 10 SIM cards, I would know which SIM is accepting the call.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here. I think the best way to do this is with a 'Whisper', using `<Number url=''>`.

The idea is that when you use a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) you can specify the number as just test:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>+447123456789</Dial>
</Response>
```

But you can also use the [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) tag:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>+447123456789</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

This allows you to use the attributes of `<Number>`, and one of those is `url=`. This can point to some TwiML that is executed on the called parties side. As a result, the customer calls your shop, which calls your mobile, which runs TwiML such as:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Incoming call from shop 'Owl Emporium'</Say>
</Response>
```

Then you know the call is from 'Owl Emporium' instead of 'Strigiformes R Us' (or whatever your shops are called). The customer who called you will not hear this message, we call it a 'whisper'.

An alternative solution is to use the `callerId` attribute so that the call is from one of your shops. You can then add this to your address book, but you won't have the customers number available as easily, so you'll need to grab that from your application if you want to call them back. It depends on which works best for you.

Hope this helps!